# Expose Liferay functions to another web application

Tags: java, liferay, server-communication

Here's my situation: I'm running a JBoss 7 in Domain Mode with several nodes. One node is in charge of my Liferay 6.2 another one runs several other web applications. Now I'd like to implement some kine of Single Sign On routine. So to use my web applications you have to go through liferay first. Authenticate agains liferay, then go one to one of the web applications.

So the question is whether there is a way to expose some of liferays methods to access the user store and check if the user, who's accessing a web application is the same as logged in on liferay. Developing some sort of bridge is fine with me. I'm thinking of a portlet which does all the interaction with liferay and exposes some methods like `readUser()`. Maybe I can do a jndi lookup for this portlet or a component embedded in this portlet to call `readUser()` from my other web applications. I think this sounds a bit like EJB stuff.

Using Liferays API, Services and LocalServices to read user information etc. shouldn't be that difficult (already played a little with that). I just don't know how to establish a communication between a web application and liferay.

If it's not working this way, I would settle for something else, maybe a webservice or an other way that makes sense but I'd like to try the EJB/JNDI approach first (except this makes completely no sense). Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Turning my applications into portlets is not really an option because these applicaions are quite large and already exsist for quite some time. So I'd like to leave them mostly unchanged - outside of auth stuff.

Thanks and regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service builder and you expose your service as remote.

Answer (score 0):

Several Options:

- Just access Liferay's API methods from your applications. You can access the JSON API at http://www.example.com/api/jsonws.
- There's also a SOAP interface (http://www.example.com/api/axis), that's typically available only from localhost (you can configure otherwise in portal-ext.properties)
- You can encapsulate calls to those services by creating your own services. Use the tool of your choice or Liferay's servicebuilder. You can create empty entities and just refer to Liferay's own entities. Servicebuilder will generate JSON or SOAP WS if you let it. (what Slimen Belhajali mentioned)

As you specifically talk about the check for user identity, you might even want to think of a completely different solution and just look at single-sign-on (SSO) solutions. This way you'd sign in only once (to the SSO server) and automatically (implicitly) to your webapp as well as to Liferay. This works best if both access the same userstore, e.g. on LDAP.